# Событие добавления элемента в Hashtable

Tags: c#

У меня есть объект типа `Hashtable`, необходимо создать событие, которое бы отслеживало добавление элемента и указывало бы ключ, по которому я добавляю элемент.

Я правильно понимаю, что если я хочу такое реализовать, мне придется создать свой класс по типу `Hashtable`, где я реализую все необходимые события?

Comment: [#](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%81%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не нужно создавать свой собственный `Hashtable` полностью с нуля, вы можете расширить существующий:

```
class ItemAddedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public object Key { get; }

    public ItemAddedEventArgs(object key)
    {
        Key = key;
    }
}

class MyHashtable : Hashtable
{
    public event EventHandler<ItemAddedEventArgs> ItemAdded;

    public override void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        base.Add(key, value);
        ItemAdded?.Invoke(this, new ItemAddedEventArgs(key));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Я думал примерно о таком, но из-за нехватки знаний не понимал, как сделать.